# Magento2: Download Custom CSV

Tags: magento-2.0

I am looking for the alternative of _processDownload() function which is available in magento1.

I have tried to use the below snippet but it is not generating file.

```
$pdf = \Zend_Pdf::load($this->directory_list->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);

$fileName = test.pdf;

$this->fileFactory->create(
        $fileName,
        str_replace('/Annot /Subtype /Link', '/Annot /Subtype /Link /Border[0 0 0]', $pdf->render()),
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
        'application/pdf'
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made below function for downloading the PDF.

```
$pdf = \Zend_Pdf::load($this->directory_list->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
$fileName = test.pdf;
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $pdf->render());

public function _prepareDownloadResponse($name, $content){
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
        header('Content-Type: application/download', false);
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
        header('Content-Length: '.strlen( $content ));
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
        echo $content;
        exit;          
}
```

This may be helpful to you.