# Magento2 Add line separator in mass action list in sales order grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, massaction, order-grid

I need to add line separator before my two newly created custom mass action "**Custom Action 1**" and "**Custom Action 2**" and

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got **one of the resolution** of my question. In order to add line separator between mass action just like Amasty extension. person should add this action in **listing_massaction** tag in ui component file. It belongs to sales order grid so ui component file should be **sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<action name="order_mass_separator">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_mass_separator</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">----------------</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
</action>
```

The only difference in this action with others that in this action there is no URL path define. So it is clickable but didn't do any thing.

> One more important thing you can't skip item type

I hope my answer will help others as well. if anybody want to add line between custom mass actions in sales order grid, though I am not sure but there may be other solutions as well.